# How can I manually supplement data coming from IMPORTHTML for error handling?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that grabs data from multiple web pages to list the **next** game for each team in the FIFA World Cup. I use the following to do so for the follow example of 2 teams. In reality I would like to grab for 5:

```
     =UNIQUE({
        IMPORTHTML("https://www.espn.com/soccer/team/fixtures/_/id/2869/league/FIFA.WORLD#","TABLE",1);
IMPORTHTML("https://www.espn.com/soccer/team/fixtures/_/id/475/league/FIFA.WORLD#","TABLE",1)
        })
```

The problem is that sometimes teams get eliminated and don't have a next game, so the table is deleted from the webpage and an error is returned by the above function,

How can I trap the error on each IMPORTHTML call and return an empty row instead of the whole UNIQUE function failing. Here's what the data returns when it works properly.

```
DATE    MATCH           TIME    COMPETITION TV  Opponent
Thu, Dec 1  Canada  v   Morocco 10:00 AM    FIFA World Cup  FS1 Canada
Fri, Dec 2  Serbia  v   Switzerland 2:00 PM FIFA World Cup  FS1 Serbia
```

Here's what I would like it to look like if the first IMPORT fails:

```
DATE    MATCH           TIME    COMPETITION TV  Opponent

Fri, Dec 2  Serbia  v   Switzerland 2:00 PM FIFA World Cup  FS1 Serbia
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an `IFERROR` for each `IMPORTHTML` so it doesn't affect the other values in the table?  Like this:

```
=UNIQUE({
        IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://www.espn.com/soccer/team/fixtures/_/id/2869/league/FIFA.WORLD#","TABLE",1));
IFERROR(IMPORTHTML("https://www.espn.com/soccer/team/fixtures/_/id/475/league/FIFA.WORLD#","TABLE",1))
        })
```

You can read more about the `IFERROR`formula [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304).

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use the IFERROR. The question is what I return in the case of error.  I'd need to return an empty table row that matches the format.  I have a solution to point to a static empty HTML table that I'm hosting, but I'd love to hardcode it to something like IFERROR(....,["","","","","",""]) but that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Do you have a URL that is currently failing? That way I can test it.

Comment: https://www.espn.com/soccer/team/fixtures/_/id/209/league/FIFA.WORLD

Comment: Here's one that works: https://www.espn.com/soccer/team/fixtures/_/id/471/league/FIFA.WORLD